# BrowserSync Plugin for Cordova (cordova-plugin-browsersync) not automatically refreshing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I installed a plugin [BrowserSync Plugin for Cordova](https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync) and ran this typing in console: `cordova run -- --live-reload`. And I changed code and console showing:

```
[BS] Serving files from: platforms\android\assets\www
[BS] Serving files from: platforms\ios\www
[BS] Watching files...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

But browser isn't refreshing automatically… I push F5 then browser is refreshed and my changes is showed.

Why isn’t this working?

Answer (score -1):

I've took care of this issue and created a PR. It seems that by default only ios/android files are watched.

For anyone else looking for a fix, install version from my fork:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/FDIM/cordova-plugin-browsersync
```

and open localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8000